# How to increase number of characters printed per line in Eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse, console, word-wrap

When I right-click in the Eclipse (v3.6.2) console and navigate to 'Preferences', I try setting the 'maximum character width' option to high numbers, like 800 or 1000, to prevent Eclipse from splitting a line of output across two lines, unless that line is really huge.

But this seems to have no predictable effect. Some lines that used to be split no longer are, but some other lines that are shorter in total length are still split. This is perplexing, and I wondered whether there is a definitive way to force Eclipse to print lines without splitting them, up to some max number of characters. (I had thought this is what I was changing in 'Preferences', but it cannot be, given that the output doesn't change uniformly.)

Here's some example output just printing the rows of a random 7x4 NumPy array in PyDev in Eclipse:

**Before** (with 'Fixed width console' unchecked and 'Maximum character width' line grayed-out.)

```
[ 1.         0.         0.         0.         1.         0.        -0.0999221]
[ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.
 -1.49427733]
[ 0.          1.          0.          0.          0.          1.
  0.16480027]
[ 0.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.
 -1.37390928]
```

**After** (with 'Fixed width console' checked and 'Maximum character width' set to 800.)

```
[ 1.          0.          0.          0.          1.          0.
 -1.04662609]
[ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          1.
 -0.57820969]
[ 0.         1.         0.         0.         0.         1.        -1.1370211]
[ 0.          0.          1.          0.          1.          0.
  1.05934584]
```

As you can see, it seems somewhat non-deterministic. Part of this is because the array I create is random, but even so, why is the miniscule difference in number of decimal places causing this change?

I also set the 'Displayed tab width' field to 4, and even 2, with no change in the output from above.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it here and it seems right to me... Considering that a tab is considered a single char, not 4 whitespaces -- regardless of the displayed tab width you have.

If that's your issue, you may want to report this to the Eclipse guys at eclipse.org and see if someone would like to tackle it -- or maybe do it yourself as it's all open source ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems right" to you? I'm trying to bump the line width up way way past 80 characters, yet it is still line wrapping at around 80 characters every time.

Comment: Well, I get that if you set that a tab = 4 spaces, then you're seeing more than you should, but if you think that a tab is a single char regardless of the visual representation... anyways, this is something that should be fixed at the Eclipse level (not at PyDev), so, you may want to report that at eclipse.org...